# Magento 2: Why do we need to ignore /app/etc/di.xml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I look at magento2 default `.gitignore` and found out that it is ignored.

Comment: What is your Magento version? I don't see `app/etc/di.xml` in gitignore.

Comment: I'm using magento-2.1

Comment: I cannot find. Please check the default Magento.